# What's the Formal Way of Saying: Cold Loss?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, terminology

When discussing systems which we want to be cold, but which *lose* cold by taking in heat from the ambient environment, what's the "I'm a smart physicist" way of saying "cold loss"?

If I were discussing loss of heat from a kiln or an oven to the ambient environment, I would say "thermal loss to the environment".

If I want to discuss heat in the ambient environment heating up my fridge, what's the formal term to describe the desired state (cold) being lost?

Comment: I have a similar problem in my photography darkroom. If I have even the tiniest crack in the door, the darkness leaks out...

Comment: @OscarBravo lol!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Engineers would call it *heat leakage*. For refrigeration systems, the direction of the leak is into the system; for heating systems, the direction is out of the system.

Comment: This is the simplest answer - it's a leakage. It just depends on the direction. Like if water leaks _out_ of your bottle or if water leaks _into_ your boat.

Answer (score 1):

Joking aside, I think this is a reasonable question. You might be fridge designer who wants to describe the continuous power your fridge has to draw in order to maintain a low temperature. A perfectly sealed fridge, once cooled down, would require no power to remain cold. A real-world fridge has to keep switching on and off its compressor to keep the temperature down (as anyone who has slept in a studio flat will attest).

Since we're trying to describe the power used to maintain refrigeration against the undesired incoming heat leakage, you could call this the *refrigeration maintenance power*.

Comment: The jokes are very well appreciated! ;-)  I was in a warm country recently when I opened the window of our air-conditioned room and a friend said, in total earnest, "don't let the cold out". It sounded funny to my ex-physicist ears, but there really does seem to be a dearth of technical language to describe what's happening. Obviously "you'll let the heat in" would have worked, much like "you'll let the light in" would work in your case. But when describing "loss" of some quantity to environment (velocity to air resistance, KE to friction), it does seem useful to have a quantity of coldness.

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to discuss heat in the ambient environment heating up my
> fridge, what's the formal term to describe the desired state (cold)
> being lost?

The desired state is maintaining the (low) temperature of the fridge. Heat transfer to the fridge from the ambient environment increases the temperature and is therefore undesirable.

The terms "hot" an "cold" are subjective terms that should be avoided. They are usually used to describe a persons's sensation to the temperature on the skin produced by heat transfer to or from the skin. The term "lose cold" would then be equivalent to "gain hot", or in your example to increase the temperature of the system due to heat transfer from the ambient environment.

Hope this helps